# Android Listview: Can't get reliable checking behavior for CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE

Tags: android, listview, adapter, checked

Here's what I mean by weird:

1. Items usually take 2 presses to have their background colour change correctly.
2. When the list is changed, Android doesn't seem to be correctly invalidating list views as the re-used views that were checked have the checked background on the new items (that I have confirmed through the debugger are *not* checked).
3. Multiple items can have the look of being selected, and in fact "correctly" uncheck when I click on them again, except for the fact that the `ListView` reports only the most-recent item as checked.
4. The first time I check an item, I can't uncheck it by clicking it.
5. Things work more-or-less fine if I change the choice mode to `ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE` except, of course, that I don't want multiple selection.

I'm using a custom adapter and a custom layout. Oh, also, targeting 4.0.3 for now. Here's the code for the list:

```java
ListView categoryList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.categoryList);
categoryList.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
categoryList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
categoryList.setItemsCanFocus(false);
categoryList.setOnItemClickListener(categoryAdapter);
```

Here's the click listener:

```java
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
    ListView listView = (ListView) parent;  
    RemoteListItem remoteListItem = (RemoteListItem) view.getTag();

    if (remoteListItem.isEnabled()) {
        remoteListItem.action(view);
    }
    view.invalidate(); /added out of sheer desperation              
}
```

Here's the extended version of RelativeLayout I'm using:

```java
package com.sastraxi.machineshop.ui;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Checkable;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

/**
 * RelativeLayout that implements the Checkable interface.
 * Set this view's tag as a Checkable, and this layout will delegate
 * Checkable's interface methods to the tag object. 
 */
public class CheckableRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout implements Checkable {

    @Override
    public boolean isClickable() {
        return false;
    }

    public CheckableRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CheckableRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CheckableRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    /**
     * Delegates to (Checkable) getTag().
     */
    public boolean isChecked() {        
        try {
            Checkable checkableTag = (Checkable) getTag();
            return checkableTag.isChecked();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            Log.w("CheckableRelativeLayout", "Tag is not an instance of Checkable; this object won't do anything useful.");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.w("CheckableRelativeLayout", "Tag is null; this object won't do     anything useful.");
        }       
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Delegates to (Checkable) getTag().
     */
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        try {
            Checkable checkableTag = (Checkable) getTag();
            checkableTag.setChecked(checked);
            invalidate();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            Log.w("CheckableRelativeLayout", "Tag is not an instance of Checkable; this object won't do anything useful.");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.w("CheckableRelativeLayout", "Tag is null; this object won't do anything useful.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delegates to (Checkable) getTag().
     */
    public void toggle() {
        try {
            Checkable checkableTag = (Checkable) getTag();
            checkableTag.toggle();
            invalidate();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            Log.w("CheckableRelativeLayout", "Tag is not an instance of Checkable; this object won't do anything useful.");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.w("CheckableRelativeLayout", "Tag is null; this object won't do anything useful.");
        }
    }

    private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = {
        android.R.attr.state_checked
    };

    /**
     * Reflect the delegate Checkable's state in this View's state set.
     */
    @Override    
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (isChecked()) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
        }     
        return drawableState;
    }

}
```

Here's the list item type it's proxying to:

```java
public abstract class RemoteListItem implements Checkable {

    private final String name;
    private final String extra;
    private boolean enabled = true;
    private boolean selected = false;

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void toggle() {
        selected = !selected;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        selected = checked;
    }

    public RemoteListItem(String name, String extra) {
        this.name = name;
        this.extra = extra;     
    }

    public String getExtra() {
        return extra;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public abstract void action(View viewInList);

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(Boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
        RemoteListAdapter.super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public boolean isSelectable() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here's the layout that's being expanded for the items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.sastraxi.machineshop.ui.CheckableRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:padding="12dp"  
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/listitem_background">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/key"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"    
        android:inputType="none"   
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/faded_text_colour"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:inputType="none"
    />

    <ProgressBar
         android:id="@+id/progress"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
         android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
         android:gravity="right"
         android:visibility="gone"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</com.sastraxi.machineshop.ui.CheckableRelativeLayout>
```

Also, @drawable/listitem_background is a state list, which is where the checked background colour comes from. I feel so lost as to why things aren't working the way I expect them to. Seems like I'm missing a `view.invalidate()` somewhere, but I can't fathom where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new `BaseAdapter` that's saving me a **lot** of grief with every `ListView` in my project. Here's a link to the tip on github for anyone looking for a solution to similar problems.

Adapter base classes: [`SmartListAdapter`](https://github.com/sastraxi/machineshop/blob/master/src/com/sastraxi/lookmonster/SmartListAdapter.java) and [`SimplerSmartListAdapter`](https://github.com/sastraxi/machineshop/blob/master/src/com/sastraxi/lookmonster/SimplerSmartListAdapter.java)

Implementing class: [`OpenFilesAdapter`](https://github.com/sastraxi/machineshop/blob/master/src/com/sastraxi/machineshop/adapters/OpenFilesAdapter.java) implements `SimplerSmartListAdapter`.

The base classes let you choose things like whether each item is clickable, checkable, or neither; the maximum number of checked items at any one time, and provides category headers for free. It also lets you move your click handler and UI updates into the adapter as well.

The difference between the two base classes is that `SmartListAdapter` allows you to define a custom mapping from the "backing list" to the list of items that actually get displayed, useful for e.g. keeping the backing list constant and showing/hiding the items based on context. `SimplerSmartListAdapter` extends `SmartListAdapter` by defining this mapping as bijective.

Comment: Looks like a couple of your links have fudged again!

Comment: ... and they're back up. Hopefully this doesn't turn into a full-time job :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like  your first touch is giving it focus, the second registers as a click.  Set the item to unfocusable and your first touch should register as a click.

Comment: I already have `categoryList.setItemsCanFocus(false);` above. I did try adding `setFocusable(false);` to each `CheckableRelativeLayout` constructor, but it doesn't seem to change much of anything, unfortunately.

Comment: My apologies, I've never done it programatically, so I didn't look in your code for it.  I've done it in the XML with `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` Maybe (as a long shot) you could try it there.

Comment: what was your solution for properly invalidating listviews?  I'm seeing the same issue where clearing/repopulating the adapter with Checkables that have had setChecked(false) explicitly called results in a ListView with the item at the index of the previously checked index is still selected.  Going through the debugger shows that something out of my control is manually calling setChecked(true) after the fact and I cant figure out what :(